# I want to see how other websites look in different web browsers

Tags: browser, screen-capture

I have gone to a wesite call browsercam.com they allow a free trial and then make you setup a payment plan. Are there any free services that are similar to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try out [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/), its free ;)

This will also be useful if you want to look at the site in multiple different versions of the same browser (IE6, IE7, IE8 etc), without having to go through installing each version, checking the site then moving on to the next version.

Comment: Wow, I never realized that so many browsers existed

Comment: Makes installing them all yourself seem a bit more daunting huh? :)

Comment: Testing multiple versions of IE can be done easily using the developer tools in IE8.  Also good for viewing websites that don't work in IE8 or in IE8 compatability mode.  (I'm looking at you yamaha!)

Comment: I used to like Browsershots but now it's so chock full of ads you can barely see what you are doing, and half the screenshots come back blank. I'm sure they need to cover costs and everything but given that the screenshot "factories" are provided by volunteers it feels a bit cheeky.

Answer (score 3):

[Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) is one way.

Another one would be [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) with [SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) which is much nicer integrated into web authoring tools. But you need some browsers for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/), of course.  They have a free version of their service that might fit your needs.

Litmus is made by the folks that make doctype, which is another member of the Stack Overflow League of Justice.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html) , from Adobe, which "provides web designers exact renderings of their web pages in multiple browsers and operating systems". The list is limited but it's working alright.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use some addons, such as those in Firefox, under Windows, that will actually launch an IE session, from inside of Firefox, which means that for the two biggest browsers, you can test them under a single program, Firefox.

As well, Opera also has some settings where you can "fake" the actual browser name reported to the web server.

JF

Comment: The `User-Agent` string shouldn't really change the rendering, though. And if it does, it's very likely that it doesn't do what it's intended to do since you're viewing it with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

this one's been really good to me.  you can run multiple IE versions concurrently and see how things look in say ie5 vs ie7, etc.  good stuff

Answer (score 0):

http://spoon.net/browsers/ - this site allows you to download and run multiple browsers AND versions of browsers without needing to actually install them. They each get virtualized into their own little sandbox automatically. I've used this site QUITE regularly for testing our sites we design.